# Get FileSystemEntry from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React when drag and dropping a folder/file I get a `FileSystemEntry` as input. However when using `<input/>` it gives `File` or `FileList`. Is it possible to get `FileSystemEntry` on using input? I find this very much more efficient as it doesn't load every directory recursively at once only when loading the files of the directory you want.

I have tried using `webkitdirectory` prop and `directory` prop aswell as `multiple` but none of those give the desired effect.

Comment: To work with FileSystemEntry objects in React, you would typically need to use the File System Access API directly, which involves requesting the necessary permissions from the user and handling asynchronous operations to read or manipulate files and directories

Comment: @RanjithBhaskaran Thanks for your response! When drag and dropping files I experience no issues. However when using directory uploads with `<input/>` indeed the browser warns me. As drag and dropping doesn't cause issues I assume it must be possible? Absolutely not sure. Also not too many information about this.

Comment: I am sorry, I think currently, it's not possible to directly obtain FileSystemEntry objects from the <input> element in HTML. I am not an expert, but can you try react-dropzone library?